# Identify old Fuji film from 1987

Tags: film, fujifilm, scanning, negative-film, negative-scanner

I have a set of old color film negatives that I want to feed to a PlusTek OpticFilm 7600i film scanner. The scanning software is VueScan (it used to be SilverFast).

The main problem I have, is that I can't identify the film. This is needed if I want to avoid applying magic by hand for every color negative scanned (due to the film and emulsion specifics).

So far I have to rely on the following metadata:

- Brand: Fuji
- Film info at top: "Fuji - 36"
- Sensitivity & emulsion information: 100 • 610B (I suppose it means: 100ASA, emulsion code: 610)
- Likely date of purchase: Q4/1986 or Q1/1987 (it features a shot of the partial eclipse of March 29, 1987)
- Country purchased: Brazil
- Bar code at bottom is not the "full" DX barcode, but rather:

  ```
  xxxxx x x x x x x x xxx
  x x x    x     x    x x
  ```

Due to the shorter barcode at the bottom of the film, the [online DX decoding applet](https://www.imageaircraft.portfairy.town/DXsim/) is of no use.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Why do you need to identify the film? Why not just scan it and then work in post production until the digitised image looks right

Comment: What is the format size of the film?

Comment: Format is standard 35mm film (24x36mm). I was hoping to avoid having to nudge and tweak too many settings by selecting a suitable film setting for the scanner.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but I found this doc online - it's a [pdf about FujiFilm film codes and notches](http://gastonline.free.fr/Files/Film%20frame%2035mm/FujifilmNotchCodes.pdf).

Comment: From that PDF data sheet, I can only infer with some level of confidence that the film type is Fuji "RAP" (emulsions 601 and up). The "B" after the emulsion number probably refers to Brazil (Fuji Film do Brasil).

Comment: Can you contact FUJI film directly? Their tech support have their heads on straight and are quite helpful

Answer (score 1):

ShutterFreak,

1. Here's the complete Fuji Professional Film Data Guide, as supplied by FujiFilm Americas in Brazil: http://en.fujifilmamericas.com.br/shared/bin/ProfessionalFilmDataGuide.pdf
   (the PDF linked above is section 1-3)
2. Are you able to read the edge markings on the film? In the file, zoom in with your PDF viewer. You'll see that the film type is actually written in text on the edge of the film.

If it's RAP (ie Astia 100), it will say "RAP100F" on the edge of the film - and it's an E6 35mm *slide* film. See page 51 for more technical details that you probably don't want.

If it's NPL160 as another has suggested, then

- Your problem is that NPL160 doesn't come in 35mm size. It *is* a good long exposure negative film... but someone would have had to mangle the film for 35mm use??? Details on p61.
- If it is NPL160 and 120 or other size, it should have NPL on the edge
- If NPL160 from a sheet, there would be edge notches on one negative.

At the very least, an interesting puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

Fuji RAP is 100 ASA professional reversal (i.e. slide/transparancy, not negative) film. So, let's see... It looks like you're mis-reading that PDF. Your film is not a Fuji*chrome* (reversal), but a *Fujicolor*. According to my reading of that PDF, we should look at NPL 160, which seems to be called 810, now: https://www.fujifilmusa.com/shared/bin/AF3-810E.pdf